# Why does BCRYPT_RNG_DUAL_EC_ALGORITHM get removed from CNG API on Windows 10?

Tags: random-number-generator, nsa, dual-ec-drbg

On article at => [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/SecCNG/cng-algorithm-identifiers)

> CNG Algorithm Identifiers

I notice that `BCRYPT_RNG_DUAL_EC_ALGORITHM` is now removed since Windows 10.

> Beginning with Windows 10, the dual elliptic curve random number generator algorithm has been removed. Existing uses of this algorithm will continue to work; however, the random number generator is based on the AES counter mode specified in the NIST SP 800-90 standard. New code should use `BCRYPT_RNG_ALGORITHM`, and it is recommended that existing code be changed to use `BCRYPT_RNG_ALGORITHM`.

Does this imply that Elliptic Curve PRNG is considered unsecure already?

The Government's elliptic curve backdoor is real, isn't it?

Comment: Also note that Dual-EC was quite slow, barely used and prone to either having a NSA-based backdoor in the default parameters and was also prone to having its parameters replaced for a custom backdoor (which actually happened!).

Comment: We do not need proof to distrust anything.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes in this case we actually even have proof to distrust it ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> The Government's elliptic curve backdoor is real, isn't it?

We don't know for sure, but there are indicators into that direction. More importantly though,

- yes, [you can backdoor the RNG, as was pointed out shortly after its publication (PDF)](http://rump2007.cr.yp.to/15-shumow.pdf)
- yes, [the parameters have been replaced in-the-wild by attackers to break VPN appliances using this RNG](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/376).

> Does this imply that Elliptic Curve PRNG is considered unsecure
>   already?

As you saw above, using Dual-EC *can* be a real exploitable risk. There are however additional reasons why Dual-EC isn't the greatest random number generator and why people wouldn't want to use it:

- It's no longer in the list of NIST specified RNGs and [was removed from SP 800-90A rev.1](https://www.nist.gov/news-events/news/2014/04/nist-removes-cryptography-algorithm-random-number-generator-recommendations).
- It's *very* slow compared to all the other "approved" RNGs (like three orders of magnitude slower).
- It doesn't even have a security proof, which is the only reason why you would want to use such a slow RNG in the first place and more specifically...
- [It's output is actually distinguishable from random](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/190) (which is like the bare minimum of a security guarantee no RNG should violate)!

So TL;DR: **Yes, the Dual-EC is backdoorable and slow and not even properly random and was probably dropped because of that.**

Additional reading: [Matthew Green's blog post on the subject](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2013/09/18/the-many-flaws-of-dualecdrbg/) (which is also a source for this answer) as well as [Bernstein's, Lange's and Niederhagen's "Dual EC: A Standardized Back Door"](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/767).

Comment: Another paper: [Dual EC: A Standardized Back Door](https://pure.tue.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/3854147)

Comment: @allo (1) NSA was informed about Dual-EC exploitation April 2005. (2) Dual EC made appearance in the industry standard body SP 800-90 in June 2006. (3) A month later, Dual-EC exploitation appeared in public patent filing in July 2006. So I guess what we can bring home is that standardization an exploit always takes a shorter length of time than writing a quiet patent for approximately 30 days. So that the public perception is that the standard would be just accidentally naive.